# PHP - Pagination Not Displaying Page Links (buttons)

Tags: php, pagination

Ive a trying to get pagination to work to display my data on separate pages. Its seems to be pulling the data from the database fine and splitting them up. The problem seems to be with the page links they aren't showing up.

here is the test page I am working on: http://jonathanlowe.co.uk/testsite/uploadform/page.php

---

```
<?php

/*connecting DB here.*/
include('dbconnect.inc.php');

$tbl_name="detail";       //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 1;

/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "page.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 1;                                 //how many items to show per page
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">� previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>"; 

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next �</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}

?>


<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {


        echo "<div class='wrapper'>";

        echo "<div class='box'><strong> Company: </strong>" . $row['company_name'] . "</div>";

        echo "<div class='box'><strong> Ref: </strong>" . $row['ref'] . "</div>";

        echo "<div class='box'><strong> Website: </strong>" . $row['website'] . "</div>";

        echo "<div class='box'><strong> Email: </strong>" . $row['email'] . "</div>";

        echo "<div class='box'><strong> Telephone: </strong>" . $row['tel'] . "</div>";

        echo "<div class='box'><strong> File Server Location: </strong>" . $row['location'] . "</div>";

        echo "<div class='box'><strong> Design From Website: </strong>" . $row['fromweb'] . "</div>";

        echo "<div class='box'><strong> Add QR Code: </strong>" . $row['qr'] . "</div>";

        echo "<div class='line'></div>";

        echo "<strong> Message: </strong>" . $row['message'] . "</br></div></p>";

        echo "</div>";

    }
?>
```

Comment: As others answered, print it. But, also add quotes around `num` at here: `$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the last add line to show the paging `<?php echo $pagination; ?>`

To look well you can also use the following css.

```
div.pagination {
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 3px;
    }

div.pagination a {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #AAAADD;

    text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
    color: #000099;
}
div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active {
    border: 1px solid #000099;

    color: #000;
}
div.pagination span.current {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000099;

    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000099;
    color: #FFF;
}
div.pagination span.disabled {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;

    color: #DDD;
}
```

Comment: Silly me, works now and thanks for the css looks a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

you must

```
echo $pagination;
```

in your code to make it visible